# iPad Pro. Disable native 2732‑by‑2048 resolution

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, launch-screen

Need to disable the iPad Pro native 2732‑by‑2048 resolution for my app.

I found that it was auto activated if the app use a Launch Screen(LaunchScreen.storyboard).

Is there a way to disable iPad Pro and continue to use Launch Screen.

(I'm surprise that even with no icon for iPad Pro, the native mode was activated, i'm sure a lot of dev don't have the app ready for this)

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? @Franck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official answer from Apple:

If an application includes a launch storyboard and is built with Xcode 7.1 or later, that application will run at native resolution on the iPad Pro regardless of whether the application includes a 167x167 icon.

If you would like to see this behavior changed in a future version of iOS, I suggest you file a bug report.  Bug reports  can be filled by visiting http://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: can I gen a link to apple doc where it says that?

Comment: Or in other words:  Install an older version of XCode (< 7.1) and use that.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using LaunchScreen.xib or LaunchScreen.storyboard? If so, if the version of Xcode you use supports the iPad Pro, it will compile the LaunchScreen for everything Xcode supports.

You could use an older version of Xcode which does not recognise the iPad Pro as you don't need it.

Or you could use Images.xcassets and not provide an iPad Pro launch image, though according to what you're asking, this doesn't seem that suitable. You could always use the LaunchScreen.xib/storyboard as the initial storyboard, so as far as the app is concerned, you're using LaunchScreen.storyboard instead of Main.storyboard. Though not providing an app icon should hold all this back, as it does with my current apps. Perhaps file a bug report with Apple? Hope this helps!